# code to read a file into sections skips the even-numbered ones

Tags: python, io, yield

The input file has the following format

```
#HEADER1, KEY1=VALUE1
 this is the first section, and it can span

 several lines, until a new section is found (which starts with the # character)
#HEADER2, KEY1=VALUE1, KEY2=VALUE2, ..., KEYn=VALUEn
second section here
again
it
can span
several lines
#HEADER3...
a;lkadflkasdf
...

#HEADER3
yet another section
#HEADERn
contains the nth section
```

Now I have the following code that attempts to read the sections:

```
def get_sections(fit):
  for lno, section in fit:
    if section.startswith("#"):
      yield itertools.chain(
        [lno,section],
        itertools.takewhile(lambda i: not i[1].startswith('#'), fit))


def read(self, filename):

  with open(filename) as fh:
    fit = enumerate(iter(fh.readline, ''), start=1)   
    for section in get_sections(fit):

      lino, header, *data = section
      header = header.strip()
      print("___"*10)
      print("<{}>".format(header))
      print("[{}]".format(data))
```

This code outputs the following:

```
<#HEADER1, KEY1=VALUE1>
[[(2, ' this is the first section, and it can span\n'), (3, ' \n'), (4, ' several lines, until a new section is found (which starts with the # character)\n')]]
______________________________
<#HEADER3...>
[[(12, 'a;lkadflkasdf\n'), (13, '...\n'), (14, '\n'), (15, '\n')]]
inside assign
______________________________
<#HEADERn>
[[(18, 'contains the nth section')]]
inside assign
```

I don't understand why the code is skipping even sections. It seems to me that after I conclude the first section, the header of the second section is already read to conclude the first section and then this line is lost. Can I make this code work at all?

Answer (score 0):

[iterools.takewhile()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) actually consumes the element which breaks the condition. So in your case it will consume the first line which starts with `#`, e.g each even header line.

Comment: Is there a way I can avoid that? Somehow to get back to the state of the iterator prior to breaking the condition?